# How to add TabIndex property on JSON file?

Tags: c#, html, angular, types

[image: This is the JSON file, from where i described the fields]

I explained HTML fields in JSON file, how to use TabIndex property on JSON file?

Answer (score 0):

Could you give more information please what you are trying to do?
By the information you give now i would suggest you give all the html elements that need a tabindex a property called tabIndex with a value and use angular databindings to bind the json to your html page.
This could be a comment but i don't have enough points